Why is CommandLineParser --Version returning gibberish at the end of the version number?
I am using the CommandLineParser NuGet package and it has built-in support for a --version switch.
When I try it in the console I get:
D:\My Programs\2022\MSATools\MSATools\bin\Release\net8.0>msatools --version
MSATools 2024.04.05+9a5b4ec4befbf650d71bc45a692f944dd1ec0f43

Why is it adding the gibberish on the right?
I have set the version information in project properties in the Package section. I appreciate there is this question:
Command Line Parser Library .NET being able to retrieve version number
It has an answer suggesting we override the option. But why is it happening in the first place?

It's the Git commit hash of the current branch. Certainly not "gibberish".

@madreflection  Thanks for clearing that up. I would not have realised that it was a commit hash! I'll have a hunt in the documentation then.

It's getting the version from the AssemblyVersionInformational attribute, which is being generated for you. You can opt out of the hash using this answer.

@madreflection All good!
